# AnyChart coloring grid on Android

Tags: java, android, linechart, palette, anychart

Im implementing AnyChart LineChart in my Android app and struggling to display coloured grid.

What I'd like to achieve in terms of the background (not a chart type) is:
https://playground.anychart.com/docs/v8/samples/AGST_Axes_Basic_11

I manage to display the data however as soon as I put the code responsible for coloring the grid the chart is not displayed. Here's the code:

```
    String[] rangeColors = new String[] {"#ff0000", "#00ff00"};
    cartesian.yGrid(0).palette(rangeColors);
    cartesian.yGrid(0).palette().count(10);
    cartesian.yScale().minimum(390).maximum(859);
    cartesian.yScale().ticks().interval(10);
```

If I remove the line:

```
cartesian.yGrid(0).palette().count(10);
```

Then the chart displays with the yGrid coloured but it's green and red intertwined in a way one interval is green next red then again green and so on.

Rest of the code related to the chart comes from the example:
https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/anychart/sample/charts/LineChartActivity.java
The only difference is Im having only 1 data series instead of 3.

Could anyone help me get the example work in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient steps count feature is provided by `RangeColors` class, so you should use this class instead of `Palette`. That's why calling `count(10)` leads to an exception.

The code below describes how to achieve the required coloring:

```
        RangeColors palette = RangeColors.instantiate();
        palette.items("#ff0000", "#00ff00");
        palette.count(10);
        cartesian.yGrid(0).palette(palette);
```

The result on the screenshot below:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9D3r.png)